# tbl_df is transformed as list in S4 class

Tags: r, r-s4, tibble

When I tried to use `tbl_df` in S4 classes, `tbl_df` slots seems to be transformed into `list`.

```
library('tibble')
setOldClass(c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame'))
setClass(Class = 'TestClass', slots = c(name = 'character'), contains = 'tbl_df')

tmp1 <- new('TestClass', tibble(x = 1:5, y = 1, z = x ^ 2 + y), name = 'firsttest')
tmp1@.Data
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[2]]
[1] 1 1 1 1 1

[[3]]
[1]  2  5 10 17 26
```

Can I visit the `tmp1@.Data` just like a `tbl_df` object? like

```
tmp1@.Data
# A tibble: 5 x 3
      x     y     z
* <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     2
2     2     1     5
3     3     1    10
4     4     1    17
5     5     1    26
```

Answer (score 1):

S3 objects, just for simplification, are lists with an special attribute "class" which is used to call the correct generic function. `print` is a generic function that is being called when R outputs the `tibble` object.

```
library(tibble)
tb <- tibble(x = 1:5, y = 1, z = x ^ 2 + y)

dput(tb)
#structure(list(x = 1:5, y = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), z = c(2, 5, 10, 
#17, 26)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
#"data.frame"))

attributes(tb)
#$`names`
#[1] "x" "y" "z"
#
#$row.names
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
#
#$class
#[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

When you create an S4 class using an S3 parent class, R only store the list on the `.Data` slot. R still keeps the attributes of the S3 objects but not in the `.Data` slot. When you print the `TestClass`, you get the tibble output plus the S4 slots. If just want the S3 object you can use `as(object,"S3")`.

```
setOldClass(c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame'))
setClass(Class = 'TestClass', slots = c(name = 'character'), contains = 'tbl_df')
tmp1 <- new('TestClass', tibble(x = 1:5, y = 1, z = x ^ 2 + y), name = 'firsttest1')
tmp1
#Object of class "TestClass"
## A tibble: 5 x 3
#      x     y     z
#* <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1     2
#2     2     1     5
#3     3     1    10
#4     4     1    17
#5     5     1    26
#Slot "name":
#[1] "firsttest1"

attributes(tmp1)
#$`names`
#[1] "x" "y" "z"
#
#$row.names
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
#
#$.S3Class
#[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
#
#$name
#[1] "firsttest1"
#
#$class
#[1] "TestClass"
#attr(,"package")
#[1] ".GlobalEnv"

as(tmp1,"S3")
## A tibble: 5 x 3
#      x     y     z
#* <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1     2
#2     2     1     5
#3     3     1    10
#4     4     1    17
#5     5     1    26
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Use `contains = class(tibble())` in `setClass()`. More details see https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/618